# ASP.NET Core Identity in My project. But error shows up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I trying to use the asp.net core Identity in my project. Below I attached the code startup.cs and partially DataContext.cs. When trying to build error shows:

*Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactor .....
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[DatingApp.API.Models.User,DatingApp.API.Models.Role,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.Int32]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)*

But If I remove the Identity Builder (see Comments) then it runs successfully I have no idea what is causing this problem. Please Anyone help to figure it out. Thanks in Advance.

startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {   
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            ConfigureServices(services);
        }


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           // This Part causing the Error
           // If I comment this part then no error

            IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
           {
               opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
               opt.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
               opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
               opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
           });

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
            builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
            builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
            builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();

            // Ends
        }
```

DataContext.cs:

```
public class DataContext :  IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int,
        IdentityUserClaim<int>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>,
        IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}

        public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        //public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole => 
            {
                userRole.HasKey(ur => new {ur.UserId, ur.RoleId});

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                    .IsRequired();

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

            builder.Entity<Like>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.LikerId, k.LikeeId });


            builder.Entity<Like>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Likee)
                .WithMany(u => u.Likers)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikeeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<Like>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Liker)
                .WithMany(u => u.Likees)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.LikerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Sender)
                .WithMany(m => m.MessagesSent)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Recipient)
                .WithMany(m => m.MessagesReceived)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the reason you are instantiating a new builder (`builder = new IdentityBuilder(...)`) manually? Try removing that line and see if it works. Otherwise please share the whole stack trace of the exception (edit your question and insert it).

Comment: I found my fault . It was here: builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>() 
I am using the type DbContext instead of my DataContext. It cost me a lot.

Comment: Cool, I'm still wondering though. Are you sure you need that line with `builder = new IdentityBuilder(...`? It doesn't seem right to me